# Bug in how node handles objects?

Tags: node.js

I need to dynamically create a JS object based on information which is also dynamically, and to some extent random.

I discovered that if(for example):

```
var dynamicname = "xyz";
var obj = {};
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {

   obj[dynamicname] = {[i] : "Sample text"};
   i++;
}

console.log(obj); //output :  {9 : "Sample text"}
```

This prevents the creation of fully dynamically created objects since it isn't possible to give a property-name more than 1 value.

Unless I've completely missed a point here this makes making objects like I need to more or less impossible.

- Is there a reason for it being like this/why?
- How would I go about making the type of JS object I need to make?

Comment: Did you expect an object like `{1:<>,2:<>,3:<>,...}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no bug. You just have a misunderstanding of what object literals are.

Every time you do this:

```
var x = {}
```

It is compiled to this:

```
var x = new Object();
```

This means, your line:

```
obj[dynamicname] = {[i] : "Sample text"}
```

Is compiled to:

```
obj[dynamicname] = new Object(); // this replaces previous value
obj[dynamicname][i] = "Sample text";
```

What you want instead is to create just one object and keep adding properties with the name `i` to it. So the code should really be:

```
var dynamicname = "xyz";
var obj = {};
var i = 0;
obj[dynamicname] = {}; // create just one object
while (i < 10) {
   obj[dynamicname][i] = "Sample text"; // keep adding properties to the object
   i++;
}
```

Comment: When trying to dynamically add properties with "depth" like this, it returns an error saying that, in this case, it cannot read *the value of i" of undefined.

Comment: If it says that then you have forgotten to create the object: `obj[dynamicname] = {}`. Cannot read the value of undefined means that `obj[dynamicname] == undefined` instead of `{}`